# Cake PHP asynchronous overlay renders wrong view

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

My cake php application seems to be messing with my overlays, in which I am loading content from another view. It works like the following:

```
//Show project settings
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.project-edit').on('click', function () {
        overlay_start('projects/show_project_settings');
    });
});

//Function for overlay
function overlay_start(path) {
    $('#overlay-center').load(path);
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(200);
    $('#overlay-center').fadeIn(200);
}
```

This is my ProjectsController's method:

```
//Display project settings overlay
public function show_project_settings() {
    $this->render('/Elements/editable/ProjectSettings');
}
```

I am on projects/index, and upon clicking a link the overlay loads. It does in fact load, however, it simply loads the same view I am already on - not ProjectSettings.ctp.

Something tells me I am missing something in the projects controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried an absolute path? `overlay_start('/projects/show_project_settings');`

Comment: @jeremyharris Then it doesn't load anything...

Comment: Does visiting the url work? Also, what does Firebug say about the request - success, failure, etc.

Comment: @jeremyharris Visiting the url works fine; projects/show_project_settings renders the same view as projects/index. Firebug gives me a "200 OK"

Comment: @jeremyharris The controller doesn't seem to know it has that function `show_project_settings` - when I try to render a random url like "projects/dsfdf", it also gives me the same thing.

Comment: That means the url is either invalid, the action is private (doesn't look like it is based on your code), or ACL or Auth is blocking it. If that were the case, though, visiting it in the browser would produce the same result.

Comment: @jeremyharris Visiting it in the browser _does_ produce the same result. How can I fix this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22418/discussion-between-jeremyharris-and-charles)

Comment: @jeremyharris I found out what the problem was - see my answer :-) Thought maybe you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. My path was leading to:

```
.../admin/projects/show_project_settings
```

but should instead have led to:

```
.../projects/show_project_settings
```

So what I did was

```
overlay_start( $.gdUrl().root() + 'projects/show_project_settings' );
```

and then it got the path right.

It was not an authentication issue.

Comment: Odd. Using `/projects/show_project_settings` should have avoided the admin prefix, as in my first comment on the OP. Anyway, glad you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Html helper to build the url, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.project-edit').on('click', function () {
        overlay_start('".$this->Html->url(array('action' => 'show_project_settings'))."');
    });
});
```

I am assuming you are in the same controller, if not add the controller param

```
$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'your_controller', 'action' => 'show_project_settings'))
```